# Amazon Chime SDK for iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, voip

I need a voip SDK for iOS and Android, so I was checking Amazon for it. It looks to me Amazon Chime is the product. My questions are:
1. Is Amazon Chime the equivalent for Twilio, Linphone SDK etc?
2. I did not find any doc on integrate Chime for iOS/Android, is it possible or is it just support browsers with its js sdk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If Chime is not the the answer, what Amazon product is?

Answer (score 0):

Integration of chime iOS SDK. Yes it is equivalent of Twilio 
https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-ios